# Contenteditable default value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a contenteditable div and I want its initial or default value. 
In an input it would be `$(this).prop('defaultValue')`

In a div, I tried:

```
def = $(this).text()
```

This gets the initial value but it changes when the user changes the content of the div. Is there a way to get and store that initial value?

Here to check and play: http://jsfiddle.net/appqhxpc/
HTML:

```
<div id="name" contenteditable="true">name</div>
<div id="check">check</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("div").focus(function () {    
    def = $(this).text()
    $('#check').text(def);
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just assign it to a variable and store it for later? `var defaultVal = $("#name").text();`

Comment: @Andrew As I said I alreaddy use def=$(this).text() and when the user changes the content of the div this var also changes and I want a way to store only the initial value

Comment: Right, just put it outside of the `focus` function, like how @void shows in his answer.

Comment: What is wrong with the question? Why the negative point? Is there anything I can do to improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.attr()` to get the id, which is 'name'

```
$("div").focus(function () {    
    def = $(this).attr('id')
    $('#check').text(def);
});
```

Comment: I like this answer because it is simple. But it has the limitation that it has to match the value of the div with the id. In this case, it works but in many cases it is difficult to make both the same.

Comment: Well, you could give each div a name value. Like name='name', and then instead of getting the id, just grab the name: .attr('name') @Nrc

Comment: it works well with any attribute. But what if the div is really long, or the content of the div is dynamic?

Comment: If that's the case then you may want to go with a more complex solution. But this solution should work for simple static naming.

Answer (score 1):

```
var _val; // global

$(function(){
   _val = $("#name").val();
});
```

Now `_val` will always have the initial value, use it whereever you want using `window._val`

Comment: I tried here http://jsfiddle.net/950j5o09/ and it does not work. Perhaps there is something I do not understand. By the way, why do you use "window"

Answer (score 1):

check if Def is empty

```js
var def = '';
$("div").focus(function() {
  if (def == "") {
    def = $(this).text()
    $('#check').text(def);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="name" contenteditable="true">name</div>
<div id="check">check</div>
```

Comment: It works most of the times, but not always. For instance if you leave the same name...

Comment: ofcourse, it wouldnt work if the content is the same , its only tracking the original content